# Reading, Updating, and Writing updated CSV file in Python 3

Tags: python, file, csv, output

I'm creating an application to essentially act as an asset database and I'm trying to open a CSV file, read the values and update them accordingly.  I see many tutorials on how to read and write to CSV files, but I can't find one that details how to iterate over a CSV file and update individual values.  Ideally it seems to be easier to use Dictionaries as opposed to lists so I can search by keyword (Part Names).  It works for the most part, but I'm having issues writing the updated list to the CSV file.  I'm getting the following error: "line 155, in writewrow
return self.writer.writerow(self._dict_to_list(rowdict))
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file

```
def write(part_name, part_num="null"):

    with open("Database.csv", "r") as file_read:

        fieldnames=["Part_Name", "Part_Num"]
        csv_reader = csv.DictReader(file_read, fieldnames=fieldnames)

        temp_list = [] # Create temp copy of the csv file

        for line in csv_reader: # Reading the CSV file and storing it in temp_list
            temp_list.append(line)

        for line in temp_list: # Printing the original list to verify contents were read correctly
            print (line)

        for line in temp_list: # Reading each element in the list and updating the value if different from the value passed into the function
            if (line["Part_Name"] == part_name and line["Part_Num"] != part_num):
                line["Part_Num"] = part_num

        for line in temp_list: # Printing out the new vesion of the temp_list to verify updates took
            print (line)

        with open("Database.csv", "w") as file_write: 
            csv_writer = csv.DictWriter(file_write, fieldnames=fieldnames)

        for line in temp_list: # Attempting to write the updated temp_list to the csv file
            csv_writer.writerow(line)
```

Comment: Your second `with` statement is inside the first `with statement`, which may cause problems, but also your final `for` loop that attempts to write out the database is *outside* of the `with` block in which you open the file for writing, so the file is closed at that point.

Comment: Of course it was that simple...

Well thank you greatly and I apologize for wasting time posting this.  Downvotes definitely warranted.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO! I'm reviewing first posts. It looks like the issue has been solved but I want to give some tips on asking a better SO question. (We don't downvote just because a question has an obvious answer, I promise!) Ideally, your question would provide a minimal example of code demonstrating the behavior you don't understand but clearly there's a lot that could have been removed from your example.

Comment: Understood.  Thank you for the feedback.

Comment: The problem here is you are using a text file (that is what a CSV is) to do the job of a database. May I suggest to use a database? The easiest is sqlite3 which is part of the Python standard library.

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure that the file is closed (outside the `with` statement) before trying to open it again for writing:

```
import csv

def update(part_name, part_num="null"):
    fieldnames = ["Part_Name", "Part_Num"]
    data = [] # Create temp copy of the csv file

    with open("Database.csv", "r", newline="") as file_read:
        csv_reader = csv.DictReader(file_read, fieldnames=fieldnames)
        header = next(csv_reader)

        for line in csv_reader: # Reading the CSV file and storing it in temp_list
            if line["Part_Name"] == part_name and line["Part_Num"] != part_num:
                line["Part_Num"] = part_num
            data.append(line)

    with open("Database.csv", "w", newline="") as file_write: 
        csv_writer = csv.DictWriter(file_write, fieldnames=fieldnames)
        csv_writer.writeheader()
        csv_writer.writerows(data)
```

As you are using the CSV library, the files should be opened using the `newline=""` parameter.